# Can't use Command+/ to comment my code in playground

Tags: xcode, comments, swift-playground

I can't use shortcut "command + /" to comment my code in playground, no reaction.

Comment: Did you check your shortcuts?

Comment: I've checked it in "Xcode - Preference - Key bindings", it seems all right, the strange thing is, if i commend code manually with '//', i can use Command+/ to comment it out, but can't comment it back... it's only in Playground, other projects are OK.